# Windows 8.1 crash when connect to internet

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, hyper-v

This problem happened with Windows 8.1 update. When I connect to internet, Windows crash with "UNEXPECTED KERNEL MODE FAIL(fwpkclnt.sys)" and blue screen. I tried uninstall Hyper-v and it's works fine now. BUT I need Hyper-v to emulate Windows Phone. How can I slove that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've enabled all the settings from BIOS which is required by Hyper-V and also enable Hyper-V from `Control Panel`> `Programs`, and then click `Turn Windows features on or off`.

Go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but not a solution for me. I used Hyper-V and run WP emulator fine before update Win 8.1. It's all happend after I update that :(